# Importing files into sql using java

Tags: java, sql, ssis

I need a way to import a text, Excel or .csv file into a Microsoft SQL database as a new table. Normally, SSIS Packages help in directly importing these files to the database.

Is there an equivalent tool for Java which automatically reads the file and creates the table (and defines data structures)?

---

Suppose I have a very big Excel worksheet, and I want to store it as a table in my database. Is there any automated method which reads this worksheet for me and automatically generates a database table with appropriate data types?

Comment: Please provide more info then only one can help you

Comment: suppose i have a very big excel worksheet, and i want to store it as a table in my database. is there any automated method which reads this worksheet for me and automatically generates a database table with appropriate data types?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Apache POI to read the excel file, and then create the table with JDBC statements, to determine the excel cell datatype you can use:

```
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
int type = cell.getCellType();
```

and then build the SQL create statement using the determined datatypes.
One important things is the formatting of the excel sheets, each column should have the same datatype of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Framework with Batch module, wich is made to process large amount of data (file parsing & database persistence). Look for Jobs wich allow to use Readers/Writers classes. You can follow this example :

[Spring Batch Tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)